# MacMono cannot create NSImage in multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, nsimage

I'm trying to create MonoMac's NSImage in task, but it failed with "can only invoked from the UI thread". So I created a native swift project, it works fine. Here is the testing code.

PS. I'm pretty sure the Xamarin.iOS' UIImage which is the same level of NSImage in iOS works fine in task.
C#: throws exception.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    try
    {
        NSImage nsImage = new NSImage(new SizeF(256, 256));
        Console.WriteLine(nsImage);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
});
```

Swift: works fine.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
    let nsImage = NSImage(size: NSSize(width: 256, height: 256));
    print(nsImage);
})
```

Is it a bug or there is a workaround?

Comment: can verify still a bug as of 7/9/2016.

Comment: I used to contact Xamarin develop team last year, the answer is that they are running on different run-time. They don't need to fix this bug. So I think this is the reason it is not fixed by now.